# Animate UICollectionViewLayout header size causes unwanted flash cross dissolve

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Vis of problem: [http://i.imgur.com/TastPR9.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/TastPR9.gifv)

```
func animateHeaderResize(height: CGFloat) {

    let layout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout;
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height);

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded();
    }) { (finished) in
        //self.loadPosts();
    }
}
```

I am attempting to animate a change in the header size of a UICollectionView through it's UICollectionViewLayout. The resulting animation has a weird flash and stretch that might be a cross dissolve transition being triggered somewhere. I have tried many variations of setting the layout of the collection view including setCollectionViewLayout(layout:animated:) and implementing collectionView(_ collectionView: layout: referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section:) but all result in the same animation.

I have noticed that the same flash occurs when changing the item size of the collection view. Maybe this is some default behavior I can modify? Do I have to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout? I have tried searching and can't find a solution, would appreciate just a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```
func animateHeaderResize(height: CGFloat) {

    self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ 
        let layout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout;
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height);
    }, completion: { (fin) in
        self.loadPosts();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw the same issue and I could see that animation looks better if i set:

```
layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = false
```